# Unknown Query String Encoding on HTTP Request

Tags: iis

About a week ago, our IIS server started getting hits on a single page with a very long query string.  Multiple key-value pairs where both the key and the value were just random characters.  The page is always the same.  The page is shtml so it does not expect or use any query string variables.

Each hit had a completely unique query string.  Here are some examples:

```
Zgmgi=zSYF1I82nna&WopGF=NoH4zLwdxLB&V89l2=HnpJsD0FJs&MKmeop=TQqf1ih6d4&Im3ae=UOyGEB6ES5&yWpB5j=QUzTmMBz0St&iKVcYwm=n99RUVUKE2&NBnVP7=H5M2vMsOMo&Kxbzrx7=9IcEmiKIoBq&cxlJe=vnwmKaKWXT5&OnFL0=idbQiRNt76&
```

```
M5KtGSd=QOL7MuGFD15&Rw7zcXi=Jq3QmkjLsx&QtEmDNv=v7ulHE77t4T&Hpbw45=WSMfPCbZig&S14KS4=Hw3jo3tEzeZ&wgUpRz=l2KfUkO6x2&qcDox=kEFEhraHZgS&JWf1Ia=PhmyHOioHB&en6gDG7=hZHl1tNvLk&ydRFTwQ=IgmQvKse0yD&r6SHx=7G6wP1QksU&F2gwZ=6fTYKzDek7&
```

I have pasted them into a couple of decoders (uri, base64) and they don't come up with anything.  Is there something obvious that I could be missing?  I do not want to overlook some sort of attack attempt?

Comment: It might be caused by fuzzing https://owasp.org/www-community/Fuzzing So if you are sure no query string should be there you can block with IIS URL rewrite rules.

Answer (score 0):

From description, this could be a kind of DDOS attack. Attacker will send random Querystrings  request to your page.  It is a kind of flood attack, which send massive requests to make your sever overload. The querystring is just random and meaningless.

You can add this rule to your request filtering module on IIS. This rule deny all request with "=" in the querystring (actually deny all query) to .shtml file.

[image]